# Select Distinct values from datagridview1 and pass to datagridview2 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can i select distinct values from datagridview1 and pass this values to datagridview2?

I had this image i upload, would you mind to take a look for more details to my question;

[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB53n.jpg)

I already tried this code but it seems not working;

```
Private Sub GetLabandOtherFees()
        Dim DistinctValues() As String = (From row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSubjectsEnrolled.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
                                            Where Not row.IsNewRow _
                                            Select CStr(row.Cells(0).Value)).Distinct.ToArray

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvsub.Rows
            dgvsub.Rows(row.Index).Cells(0).Value = DistinctValues
        Next
    End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't you have database ? Why are you not doing this using sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
Private Sub GetLabandOtherFees()
        Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
        Dim cellValue As String = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not datagridview1.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                cellValue = datagridview1(0, i).Value.ToString()
                If Not dic.ContainsKey(cellValue) Then
                    dic.Add(cellValue, 1)
                Else
                    dic(cellValue) += 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        For Each keyvalue As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dic
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}", keyvalue.Key, keyvalue.Value))
        Next

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In datagridview2.Rows
            row.Cells(0).Value = sb.ToString()
            row.Cells(1).Value = dic.Count.ToString()
        Next
    End Sub
```